# Is Aiming for Ranged or also Melee?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

Is the aiming maneuver only for ranged weapons, or do melee weapons also apply? My group says otherwise, I just want some clarification.

Answer (score 11):

**Aim can be used with melee weapons.**

The rule for the Aim maneuver, on page 207 of the *Force and Destiny Corebook*, says:

> During combat, a character can use the aim maneuver to **steady a weapon or line up a hit** before attacking, granting a bonus to his next combat check.

At no point does it say that this bonus only applies to ranged attacks. It works with melee weapons just fine.

Comment: okay thank you I figured that was the case just needed to hear it from someone else